# Force CSS updates in wordpress w/ wp_enqueue_script only works on localhost?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

The following code in my child theme's functions.php works for localhost changes (they update live without having to clear browser cache).

However on my live site, this doesn't work. I've done an echo test on the directory and its pointing to the correct location, same as localhost.

Anyone know how to fix this please?

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
?>
```

Comment: you mean your script is not loading in page ? Have you looked at page source of the page?

Comment: CSS updates require browser cache clearing to take effect. But the function I posted corrected this issue (however only on localhost version of the site, not the live version). ---- page source is loading correct css file, problem is browser is using cache'd version of it

Comment: you can find the file that you are loading is properly displayed or not or your stylesheet code is not loading properly by inspecting the page source. You should disable the browser cache or any plugins you are using for cache. If not those two are then server might have some cache issue.

Comment: @react Check the resulting `<link>` tag and make sure the timestamp is changing. I believe some browsers bypass cache on `localhost` URLs, which would explain your issue.

Comment: When I disable caching in my browser, the updates take effect on live site (not sure if this information helps much). <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-styles-css'  href='http://www.mysite/.../style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: @ceejayoz you are correct in the bypassing of cache for localhost... removed the function and it still worked. So the function I posted was never working to begin with

Comment: @react There should be a `?ver=12345` sort of thing at the end of the `href` there, so something's not working right. Check that the `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' )` is generating what you expect.

Comment: solved by adding "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />" to the header instead of the functions file with wp enqueue. It wasn't versioning before but it is now. Thanks!!

Comment: @react That's going to mean this file is *never* cached though, as the timestamp will always be different. Not ideal for users. Should see why `filemtime` is returning `null` or `false`.